# Android: Add indeterminate ProgressBar to View

Tags: android, progress-bar

Pretty simply question; the title says most of it.

Basically, while Parse downloads the actual data for an image - which is nicely handled by `ParseImageView` - I'd like the UI to display a "loading" indicator on that ParseImageView.

I'm familiar with iOS, in which I can simply add one `UIView` to another `UIView`. I haven't yet found a similar paradigm with Android. Ideally, the class (either `ParseImageView` itself or a subclass I write) should be able to encapsulate this logic without the need for external layouts, image files, etc.

So, I'm looking for a way to perform the following steps **in a ParseImageView, in code**:

1. Set the `ParseFile` associated with the `ParseImageView`.
2. Tell the `ParseImageView` to begin loading the image data.
3. Create an indeterminate `ProgressBar`.
4. Add the indeterminate `ProgressBar` "on top of" (and centered in) the `ParseImageView`. (***Side note:*** getting the `ProgressBar` styled with my app's main tint color would be an awesome bonus here!)
5. When the `GetDataCallback` returns, move the `ProgressBar` from the `ParseImageView`.

Comment: Looks like this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21205693/load-an-image-in-imageview-parse-com

Comment: @DanielNugent I'm not sure if I was unclear in my question. I have no issue with actually downloading and displaying the content. My issue is that the `ParseImageView` doesn't give any indication that work is being done. That's what I'd like to fix.

Comment: I thought maybe the ProgressDialog would work for your purposes, the link above shows how that would work, see `progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Login.this, "","Downloading Image...", true);`  and `progressDialog.dismiss();`   I'm not too familiar with the ProgressBar, but this sample code of using a ProgressBar with ParseImageView might help: https://github.com/jsambuo/pic-taker/blob/master/src/com/sambuo/pictaker/ViewPictureActivity.java

Comment: @DanielNugent I'm looking for a way to add a progress indicator **per `ParseImageView`**. Since all images are downloading independently and asynchronously, it makes for a better UI. Easy enough in iOS. As usual, like pulling teeth in Android. For now, I have it working by adding a `ProgressBar` in my list item's layout, but I'd rather solve this problem **once** in the app, not in every `ListView` where I want this solution. Thanks, though!